# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP для MySQL

Tags: mysql

Если поле имеет формат `DATE` можно сделать как то `auto insert` текущей даты силами мускула как `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  для `TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, TIMESTAMP является исключением. Для других типов данных в качестве DEFAULT можно использовать только константы.
В документации http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

> Значение DEFAULT задает значение по умолчанию для поля таблицы с одним исключением: значение по умолчанию должно быть константой, оно не может быть функцией или выражением. Для примера, Вы не можете задать для поля типа DATE значение функции NOW() или CURRENT_DATE. Исключение: Вы можете задать CURRENT_TIMESTAMP как значение по умолчанию для поля типа TIMESTAMP.

Однако есть варианты:

1. Использовать TIMESTAMP в качестве типа данных.
2. Сделать триггер, реализующий требуемый функционал.

Answer (score -2):

Предлагаю следующее решение:

```
CONVERT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATE)
```